# Reading file from /src/main/resources gives exception FileNotFound

Tags: java, java-web-start, embedded-resource, jnlp

My project has the following structure:

```
KnitProject - Project Name
/src/main/java/com/knit/controller/File1.java
/src/main/resources/data/read.txt
```

In File1.java, I am trying to get the path of read.txt which is inside **/src/main/resources** folder.

```
Main.java
=========
Server server = new Server(8585);
.....
.....
server.start();
server.join();

File1.java
==========
URL url = Encrypter.class.getResource("/data/read.txt");
System.out.println(url.getFile()); //This prints "C:/Users/KnitProject/target/classes/data/read.txt" which is working locally from my system
```

When I deploy this jar in Tomcat `i.e http://<ip>:8080, /src/main/resources path is not accessible.`

```
System.out.println(url.getFile()); //This prints "http://<ip>:8080/test/target/KnitProject.jar!/data/read.txt.
```

when trying to read file using

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(url.getFile())) ---> gives me error FileNotFound Exception when deployed in Tomcat
```

I have created jar of KnitProject application and deployed it in Tomcat. Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong. **/src/main/resources/ is accessible from my local machine and same code is giving error FileNotFound Exception**.

How can I read the file which is under /src/main/resources/data. I am using Embedded Jetty server in my code and same is compilled and build as one Jar and then deployed in Tomcat. I am running jar using JNLP.

Comment: Open the jar file manually (you can use 7Zip if you are on windows) and look inside the folder structure if you see the wanted file at the wanted place under src/main/resources

Comment: How did you read the file? What is the value of url?

Comment: @Katuiros When I unzip jar, I see path like data/read.txt

Comment: @Debmalya Biswas URL url = Encrypter.class.getResource("/data/read.txt"); I have added comments in my question with output of URL local and when deployed in tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `resourceAsStream` method to read the file from jar

```
InputStream stream = Encrypter.class.getResourceAsStream(filePath)
```

Now with this stream you can proceed

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling for days to get it work.

Comment: A more comprehensive explanation: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.